# How can i append the same name of dictionary in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, nested

```
list1 = [1, 4, 1]
for frame_wf in list1:
wf[list1] = {}
wf[list1]['process'] = fit[frame.index(list1)]
wf[list1]['color'] = for_bg[frame.index(list1)]
print(wf)
```

The output:

```
{1: {'process': 31, 'color': '#49E8C1'}, 4: {'process': 41, 'color': '#101958'}}
```

My desired output:

```
{1: {'process': 31, 'color': '#49E8C1'}, 4: {'process': 41, 'color': '#101958'}, 1: {'process': 35, 'color': '#49E5B1'}}
```

The other 1 is missing, i notice that if value is repeated it won't append to the nested dictionary.

Comment: The point of using a dictionary is that each key has a unique value to it, so you can't have the same key with two different values

Comment: Dictionaries should have unique keys. You may use an external library called `multidict` to achieve this.

Comment: @RonieMartinez Cool, I never heard of multidict.  I tried implementing it with OP's code, but the code is incomplete even without the multiple-key problem.  OP, if you still need help, please make a more minimal example of what you're looking for and it looks like something could be cooked up with multidict.

Comment: @RonieMartinez sorry but i'm just new to programming, may i know how can i implement this to get my desired output? I checked multidict and i am having trouble to understand.

Comment: Here is an example from the official documentation: https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multidict.html#multidict

Comment: @RonieMartinez BIG thanks! Didn't find it earlier.